# I have data to get but still return size=0 when I access it using service with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

This is my code to access URL service

```
    public interface BukuResepMasakanAPI {
    public static String baseURL = "http://10.108.91.11/buku_resep_masakan_service/";

    //membuat Instance Retrofit
    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();




    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    @POST("detail_resep_by_jenis?")
    public Call<DetailResepModel> getDetailResep(@Query("id_jenis_resep") String id_jenis_resep);
}
```

and this is my code to call retrofit

```
 public void loadData(){
    BukuResepMasakanAPI apiService = BukuResepMasakanAPI.client.create(BukuResepMasakanAPI.class);
    DetailResepModel model = new DetailResepModel();
    Call<DetailResepModel> call = apiService.getDetailResep(idJenisResep);

    //proses call
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DetailResepModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DetailResepModel> call, Response<DetailResepModel> response) {
            DetailResepModel resep = response.body();
            Log.d("idjenisresep",""+idJenisResep+" size "+resep.getDetailresep().size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DetailResepModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("failed", "" + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

When I run my apps there is no error but I still get size =0 whereas I have data to get

Answer (score 0):

Why in your route you have a ?, if you have a get parameter Retrofit know how to do with the annotation Query, you don't have to finish your route with a ?.

But you have a POST route with x-www-form-urlencoded so i suggest you to do like that :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("detail_resep_by_jenis")
public Call<DetailResepModel> getDetailResep(@Field("id_jenis_resep") String id_jenis_resep);
```

Comment: still got the same result :(